# Can't install cups because of unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, printing, dependencies

This started after a recent update to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. My printer ceased to appear in Print dialogue and when I tried to start cups service manually I was told that the cups service was unmasked so can't be started.

I purged cusps and tried to reinstall. This is what I get:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cups
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                

Fetched 102 kB in 17s (5,858 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cups : Depends: libcups2 (= 2.1.3-4) but 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
       Depends: libcupscgi1 (>= 1.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libcupsmime1 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: cups-core-drivers (>= 2.1.3-4)
       Depends: cups-daemon (>= 2.1.3-4)
       Recommends: printer-driver-gutenprint but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.</b>
```

can anybody help me please?

Comment: Seems like it is a bug. An incorrect package must have been pushed in an official repo. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1676621

Seems like some people have posted workarounds in the bug thread. Check for example comments #3 and #14.

Comment: Yes, seems a bug alright. The workaround of 'sudo apt-get update -f' worked like a charm. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

this issue has also appeared on the Mint forums;

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=242497&start=40

the ninth post on this page .. gives a suggested solution from Houchou that seems to work also